# Discord.js TypeError: message.member.roles.find is not a function

Tags: discord.js

pls help

CODE
    case 'clear':
                if(!message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "OWNER"))

OUTPUT

```
if(!message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "OWNER"))
TypeError: message.member.roles.find is not a function
```

Comment: Hi! and welcome to stackoverflow! Would you mind [adding a little more context](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to your question? Is roles an array? Do you have additional code you can share such as the member/role models?

Answer (score 4):

`GuildMember.roles` returns an object of type `GuildMemberRoleManager`. To get the roles from this you want to use `GuildMemberRoleManager.cache`. This returns an object of type `Collection<Snowflake, Role>`. Once you have that, you can use `Collection.find(fn, [thisArg])`. BUT, in your specific case, you'd want to use `Collection.some(fn, [thisArg])`. The `some` method checks if a specific item exists based on a function.

Your code would instead look like this:

```
if(!message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "OWNER")) {
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sensei!

Comment: i have another one .

Comment: CODE

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {

    const channel = member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "welcome");
    if (!channel) return;

    channel.send(`Welcome to our server, ${member}, please read the rules in the rules channel!`)

OUTPUT
const channel = member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "welcome");
TypeError: member.guild.channels.find is not a function

Comment: Replace
`const channel = member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "welcome");`
with 
`const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "welcome");`

Please read [this](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#before-you-start) tutorial on how to update from discord.js v11 to v12.

Also, make sure to remember to mark an answer as solved if it fixed your problem and upvote the solution.